# Рехэш существующей строки

Tags: php, хеширование

`$_hash = md5(rand()); //хэш токена if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE token = '{$_hash}'")) > 0) $err = 'выполните новую попытку входа';`
Подскажите , как сделать чтобы вместо ошибки скрип генерировал новый $_hash

Comment: Токен сделайте уникальным полем - при insert будете получать ошибку, обрабатывайте её, получили ошибку - заново генерите и записываете токен. есть нечто подобное, от миллиона до полтора записей в сутки и за 3 года ещё ни разу не дублировался токен